# Custom Module config.xml not loading layout xml file

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating custom module for practicing.
`app/code/local/Amactech/Events/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

  <modules>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
  </modules>

  <global>

    <models>
      <events>
        <class>Amactech_Events_Model</class>
      </events>
    </models>

    <helpers>
      <events>
        <class>Amactech_Events_Helper</class>
      </events>
    </helpers>

    <blocks>
      <Amactech_Events>
        <class>Amactech_Events_Block</class>
      </Amactech_Events>
    </blocks>

  </global>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <events>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <frontName>events12</frontName>
          <module>Amactech_Events</module>
        </args>
      </events>
    </routers>

    <layout>
      <updates>
        <amactech_events>
          <file>events.xml</file>
        </amactech_events>
      </updates>
    </layout>

  </frontend>

</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <events_events12_index>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_left" />
  </events_events12_index>

</layout>
```

**app/code/local/Amactech/Events/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

    class Amactech_Events_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function indexAction(){
      $this->loadLayout();
            return $this->renderLayout();
        }
    }

?>
```

So whatever whatever changes (whether right or wrong) are made into `events.xml` file does not reflect to frontend page. 
The second thing is in `events.xml` I defined `page_two_columns_left` but it is showing page with right column.
It seems that `config.xml` file is not loading `events.xml` file

Can anyone point out that what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your handler should be

```
events12_index_index
```

Instead of

```
events_events12_index
```

Comment: I tried handler events12_index_index but still not working.

Comment: @AhmarArshad `print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());` add this code in your controller index action and see which handler its showing